# How to avoid a 502.3 error (due to unknown HTTP header) when web app is behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy

[Apologies for the poorly phrased question]

Here's my situation: -

I have a web app  that inserts a custom HTTP header in its response (the header value just emits some debug performance information that was useful to me during development - it should probably never had gone out but I left it in because it was very small and I *thought* it would have minimal impact).

However this innocuous change has had a pretty dramatic effect when we try and host the app behind a reverse proxy.  When using IIS + ARR + Url Rewrite as the reverse proxy, all responses come back with the status code 502.3 Bad Gateway.

The fix is to obviously remove the header - but that would mean a re-compile.

Is there a way to configure either the proxy or the site behind the proxy t get around this issue?